# Use multi dimensional big array in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I want to create some big Arrays (about contained 100000*100000*100000 elements) for some tests. for example comparing between adding two arrays in parallel and serial way.
but i meet this exception:
[Out of Memory Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ60P.jpg)

Please Help me to complete this problem for me.
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The second troubleshooting tip looks relevant: "Be sure you have enough memory to allocate for internal purposes and new managed objects". Effectively, it sounds like you need to install more memory (RAM) in your machine. Or you could allocate some smaller arrays.

As pointed out in the comments, you would need many Terabytes of memory to allocate arrays of that size. Assuming your arrays are of type int32, you could make them of size 1000 instead, which would be 4GB.

Comment: Suppose he want an array of int32, he needs ((10^5)^3)*4 bytes ~ 3638TB of RAM. It's not possible right now :)

Comment: even a bit array will still be 113TB of ram this will make things difficult ;)

Comment: I hadn't done the maths, but that is a very good point! I'll update the answer